# Spring loading properties from a bean

Tags: spring

I am currently usinmg `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to load properties into my spring context, however I want to have a custom hierarchy/overriding of property files that I am handling in a Java class. Can I have my class, which itself is a bean in the context, inject the properties into the context?

e.g.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:/config/conf.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="config" class="com.main.Config" />
```

My Config class has a `Properties getProperties()`  method -- can I wire that into spring somehow? Obviously the properties would not be loaded until the config bean is created or inited.

Thanks!

**Update**: As suggested by the answer I change my Config to `Config extends PropertySource<Properties>` and had to write a small wrapper around `MutablePropertySources` that takes a single `PropertySource` and then my xml looks like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="propertySources">
        <bean class="com.main.ConfigMutablePropertySources">
             <constructor-arg name="propertySource" ref="config" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Where:

```
public class ConfigMutablePropertySources extends MutablePropertySources {
    public ConfigMutablePropertySources(PropertySource<?> propertySource) {
        super(new MutablePropertySources());
        addLast(propertySource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the methods available (from [JavaDoc for `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)) suggests to me no easy way to do such a thing.

The general comment at the top suggests that, as of Spring 3.1, one should prefer to use [`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) instead.  Using this solution, it appears that you could register your own set of `PropertySource` objects via the [setPropertySources(...)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html#setPropertySources%28org.springframework.core.env.PropertySources%29) method.  Of course your `Config` class would have to be fit into the interface (abstract class actually) of [`PropertySource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html).

It is worth noting that using the `setPropertySources(...)` method above will assume nothing else about your property sources and will therefore not add the default property sources (Environment and Local properties).

Comment: OK so I added a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and piped it in. I can see it initialized before my other beans, but my other beans' properties now aren't working. Getting a: Could not resolve placeholder 'pool.size'
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209) ~[org.springframework.beans.jar:3.1.1 ...

Comment: The documentation linked to the `setPropertySources(...)` method says this: `Setting this property indicates that environment property sources and local properties should be ignored.`, so you will likely need to add them in your collection of PropertySources.

Comment: I am already loading (and logging) different types of properties in my config class, but looks like for some reason they don't make it to the spring context